# Tuning of SVM Text Classifier created with RTextTools returns same performance for every hyperparameter

Tags: r, svm, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I have created a text classifier with RTextTools, but it does not perform that good. That is why I decided to tune the parameters gamma and c to improve the models' performance with the following code:

```
tc <- tune.control(cross=10)
modeltune <- tune.svm(x=tucontainer@training_matrix, y=tucontainer@training_codes, gamma= 10^(-6:1), cost = 10^(-1:1), tunecontrol=tc)
modeltune$performances
modeltune$bestmodel
```

However, I am getting the same result for every parameter combination and do not really have any idea, why.

```
   gamma cost     error dispersion
1  1e-06  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
2  1e-05  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
3  1e-04  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
4  1e-03  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
5  1e-02  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
6  1e-01  0.1 0.4307769 0.01347589
7  1e-06  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
8  1e-05  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
9  1e-04  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
10 1e-03  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
11 1e-02  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
12 1e-01  1.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
13 1e-06 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
14 1e-05 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
15 1e-04 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
16 1e-03 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
17 1e-02 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
18 1e-01 10.0 0.4307769 0.01347589
```

Does anyone know where the error is?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks ok to me, which suggests it's something to do with your data. Are you able to provide a reproducible example?